# Vue 3 not able to clearTimeOut

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, settimeout, vue-composition-api, cleartimeout

I'm learning Vue 3 doing a memory game. I have an proxy array of objects(cards),  objects have this format:

```
{
    "id": "01",
    "image": "01.jpg",
    "isFlipped": false
}
{
    "id": "07",
    "image": "01.jpg",
    "isFlipped": false
}
```

My flipCard méthodes turns card.isFlipped:true to reveal the image. When 2 cards are revealed thé compare méthode is called. If there is match cards dont unflip. If there is no match cards unflip again after setTimeOut of 1.5 seconds.
If another cars is flipped before the 1.5 seconds of setTimeOut I need to clear this timeOut to unflip the 2 revealed cards before unflipping the next one (before the 1.5 secs).I've been trying to achieve this for 2 months.
Could anybody help me out please , thanks

My component

```js
// flip 2 cards and compare them
function flipCard(card) {
  clearTimeout(timeoutId.value);
  card.isFlipped = true;
  clicksNumber.value += 1;
  comparedCards.value.push(card);

  if (comparedCards.value.length === 2) {
    compare(comparedCards.value[0], comparedCards.value[1]);
  }
}

let timeoutId = ref();
function unflip(card) {
  // Set a timeout and assign the ID to the timeoutId variable
  timeoutId.value = setTimeout(() => {
    card.isFlipped = false;
  }, 1500);
}
// compares 2 flipped cards
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.image == b.image) {
    found.value.push(a, b);
    // remove found values from not found array
    notFound.value = notFound.value.filter(
      (item) => !found.value.includes(item)
    );

  } else {
    comparedCards.value.forEach((card) => {
      unflip(card); //unflips cards agter 1.5 secs
    });
  }
  comparedCards.value = [];
}
```

I tried initializing the total clicksNumber
and the click number each time we have 2 cards to compare (stopClick )

```js
 let clicksNumber = ref(0);
let stopClick = ref();
```

and then when reaching 2 cards to compare get the click n° when this happened
and watch for it comparing to totalClicks
If these are different call clearTimeout(timeoutId)

```js
function flipCard(card) {
  clearTimeout(timeoutId.value);
  card.isFlipped = true;
  clicksNumber.value += 1;
  comparedCards.value.push(card);

  if (comparedCards.value.length === 2) {
    stopClick.value = clicksNumber.value;
    compare(comparedCards.value[0], comparedCards.value[1]);
  }
}

watch(clicksNumber, (stopClick) => {
  if (clicksNumber.value != stopClick) {
clearTimeout(timeoutId)
  }
});
```

Also tried about 20 different things that didnt work... :-(

I dont have any errors, just when clicking before 1.5 seconds I can have 3 4  or 5 cards flipped at the same time

Comment: Have you checked if `unflip` is called multiple times? (That you overwrite an already existing timeout ID without cleaning that timeout)

Comment: Unflip is called every time I have 2 cards to compare (one time for 2 flipCard times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `comparedCards` contains two items, you set two timeouts here:

```
    comparedCards.value.forEach((card) => {
      unflip(card);
    });
```

So `timeoutId` will contain only the last timeout id.

To fix this, you can either make `timeoutId` an array, or change `unflip()` to handle two cards:

```
function unflip(cards){
  timeoutId.value = setTimeout(() => {
    cards.forEach(card => card.isFlipped = false);
  }, 1500);
}
```

Btw. I don't think making `timeoutId` a ref does much for you - you will never use it in the template.

---

The second issue is that you don't actually just want to cancel the timeout. If two non-matching cards are revealed and the player flips another card, you do not just want to cancel waiting to turn the two previous cards again, but you want to unflip them right away:

```
let timeoutId = null; // <--- doesn't have to be a ref

function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.image == b.image) {
    ...
    comparedCards.value = []; // <--- cards match, remove right away
  } else {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(unflip, 1500); // <--- wait to unflip
  }
  // <--- do not clear compared cards here
}


function flipCard(card) {
  if(comparedCards.value.length >= 2){ // <-- cannot have more than two cards open at the same time
    unflip() //<--- abort timeout, unflip right away 
  }
  if (card.isFlipped) { //<--- prevent flipping the same card twice
    return
  }
  card.isFlipped = true;
  comparedCards.value.push(card);

  if (comparedCards.value.length === 2) {
    compare(...comparedCards.value);
  }
}

function unflip() {
  if(timeoutId){
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = null;
  }
  comparedCards.value.forEach(card => card.isFlipped = false); // unflip all opened cards
  comparedCards.value = [] // no more open cards
}
```

I would probably rename `comparedCards` to `unflippedCards` or something.

Comment: Hello @Moritz Thank you very much, now I'm not able to turn more than 2 cards at a time (unlesss!!! yeah I found a new bug!!!... If I click twice the same card it remains unflipped for ever even if no match! Shall I laugh or cry? Anyway the bug was there before, i just hadnt seen it)

Comment: lol yes, this is how it goes. I have added a check to the `flipCards()` method that should prevent it

Comment: OMG Thanks!!! How do you do this in 2 seconds?! Bug is gone :-)
I must confess though the setTimeOut thing works I dont fully understand yet... Gotta looong way to go still lol